# How do I say that I want something to end soon using "I would like" and "I hope" and maybe Future Perfect

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, future-tense, future-perfect

I'm wondering now how to say that I want this pandemic (or anything else) to end soon.

Is this sentence correct?

Using *I hope*:

1. I hope this pandemic will have ended by June.

is this tense Future Perfect correct to use? and is here any difference between *by June* and *in June*? or maybe I should say

2. I hope this pandemic will have been ended by June

---

Using *I would like*:

1. I would like this pandemic to end by July

or maybe in this *would like* construction should I use Future Perfect too, like:

2. I would like this pandemic will have ended by July

because I want this action to be completed by July?

---

I'm not sure if you can understand what I mean but anything you write about this, will be helpful for me for sure.

Comment: I guess it is nicer to show the effort you already made, such as 
[the definition/explanation and examples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/) or
[grammar rules and examples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/) 
in a dictionary or other trusted reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to express what you are trying to say is, "I hope that this pandemic will end by July" or "I would like this pandemic to end by July". Both sentences express the idea that you are hoping that when we get to the month of July, the pandemic will be over. You could be even shorter: "I hope this is over by July!"